# how to convert cv:Mat to vector<float> descriptors?

Tags: opencv

I met a problem when communicating with my pales in TCP. I received the data processed in an asn1 struct such as :

```
Mat ::= SEQUENCE {
        numrows   INTEGER,
        numcols   INTEGER,
        data      BIT STRING,
        type      INTEGER       
    }
```

I can construct a matrix which is cv::mat. However, now I need query it in this format: vector descriptors. So my question is how can I convert mat to this vector?

Comment: Can you show your code to initialize the `cv::Mat`? It looks like your data input is integers, but you want a vector of `float`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think, you can avoid the copy:

```
Mat m(3,3,CV_32F);
vector<float>v;
v.insert(v.begin(),m.begin(),m.end());
```